# Should activated be called before loaded event?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, event-handling, winjs

I am reading [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2012/10/29/free-ebook-programming-windows-8-apps-with-html-css-and-javascript.aspx) free ebook. On page 105, it describes the sequence in which various events are invoked and it seem to suggest that `activated` executes before `loaded`. In order to test it, I added the following simple code and added breakpoints in both methods. Problem is that the `loaded` breakpoint is always getting executed before `activated`. Am I misunderstanding something?

```
app.addEventListener("loaded", function (vt) {
    console.log("loaded");
});

app.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {
    console.log("activated");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ebook is wrong, [from the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212679.aspx):

> onactivated  occurs when WinRT activation has occurred. The name of
>   this event is "activated" (and also "mainwindowactivated").    This
>   event occurs after the loaded event and before the ready event.

Comment: Where does the doc say loaded event is invoked before activated? I don't see this in msdn link?

Comment: Actually you are right; It states this in other link at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229840.aspx

Comment: This event **occurs after** the loaded event